# Adding number from input field to specific option selected row into SQL table

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to use both an input field to add a number to a current row while also using an input field to select the specific row.

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
  <select class="form-control" id="rowid">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
</div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numbertoadd" placeholder="1,000">
  </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="height: 38px;">Remove</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried looking into other ways people have done this such as with the sql:

```
UPDATE user SET points = points + 1 WHERE id = 42
```

But i am unsure how i can use both selected fields at the same time.

Comment: What makes you unsure? Do you think there's a problem substituting multiple parameter variables into a query?

Comment: Not really sure what the problem is. `UPDATE table SET number = x where rowid = y` (where x is the number input from the textbox and y is the number input from the dropdownlist. (Obviously in reality you'd use parameters in the PHP, but this is just a simplification.)). Have I missed something? Your description of the issue is a little unclear.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the reply, i get the logic behind it i am just not clear as to how I actually push the option value into "y"

Comment: Please show us your PHP so far

Comment: @ADyson I don't have anything at the moment apart from connect and that SQL i linked. I just don't really know how it would work. I'm not really asking someone to do it for me exactly just help me understand or link to somewhere that can help! Thanks

Comment: assuming these fields are part of a HTML form, then (if you give them both a `name` attribute), when you submit the form to the server, the values will be available in the $_POST or $_GET array in PHP (depending on which HTTP method you use to submit the form). Then you can add those values as parameters in your query. You can add as many parameters as you need. Do you know how to use PHP libraries to construct and execute a SQL query? Which library are you using (e.g. PDO, mysqli, sqlsrv etc)? What database engine are you connecting to? (e.g. mysql, SQL Server, Oracle etc)

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a ton for the explanation i worked the rest out am using the GET array and its working amazing! Thanks.

Comment: Ok great. Maybe you should find some tutorials/examples of using HTML forms with PHP, it seems like you had a few basic gaps in your knowledge. Good luck for the rest of your project.

Comment: @ADyson for sure I do, I am just solo learning as i go. For some reason i didn't think about GET or POST then putting that into the statement. That sentence alone from you helped me solve it. Thanks again!